# Obtener historial de un ticket(ID) el cual esta en la misma tabla. MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes tengo la siguiente tabla

[image: Tabla en mi base de datos]

quisiera hacer una consulta donde el resultado sea el historial del ticket Para el ejemplo que se mira sería lo siguiente

```
--------------------------------------------
|account     |  ticket      |comment        |
---------------------------------------------
|9962708     | 633225601    |to 633226153   |
|9962708     | 633226153    |from 633225601 | 
---------------------------------------------
|9962708     |633382901     | to 633389262  |
|9962708     |633389262     | to 633389339  |
|9962708     |633389339     | to 633389451  |
|9962708     |633389451     | from 633389339|
---------------------------------------------
```

**Actualizacion**
Tengo unas consultas anidadas en mi proyecto las cuales me repiten un registro  del historial, quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de hacerlo.

```
$tampil = $koneksi->prepare("SELECT ticket,symbol,lot,ordertype,orderprofit,orderswap,comment FROM mt4history WHERE comment LIKE '%to%' ORDER BY ticket");
$tampil->execute();
$tampil->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($data = $tampil->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT))
  {
   $ticket = $data['ticket'];
   $comment = $data['comment'];
    ? >
   <tr class = "tablecell"  id = "<?php echo $data['ticket']; ?>" >
   <td> <? php echo $data['ticket'];? > < / td >
   <td> < / td >
   <td> <? php echo $data['symbol'];? > < / td >
   <td> <? php echo $data['lot'];? > < / td >
   <td> <? php echo $data['type'];? > < / td >
   <td> <? php echo $data['orderprofit'];? > < / td >
   <td> <? php echo $data['orderswap'];? > < / td >
   <td> <? php echo $data['comment'];? > < / td >
   < / tr >
   < !-- SUBCONSULTA -- >
   <? php
   $coment_partial = explode(" ", $comment);
   echo $coment_partial[0];
   echo $coment_partial[1];
   $tampil1 = $koneksi->prepare("SELECT ticket,symbol,lot,ordertype,orderprofit,orderswap,comment FROM mt4history WHERE ticket = $coment_partial[1]");
   $tampil1->execute();
   $tampil1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   while($data1 = $tampil1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT))
     {
       ? >
      <tr class = "tablecell "  id = "<?php echo $data1['ticket']; ?>" >
      <td> <? php echo $ticket ? > < / td >
      <td> <? php echo $data1['ticket'];? > < / td >
      <td> <? php echo $data1['symbol'];? > < / td >
      <td> <? php echo $data1['lot'];? > < / td >
      <td> <? php echo $data1['type'];? > < / td >
      <td> <? php echo $data1['orderprofit'];? > < / td >
      <td> <? php echo $data1['orderswap'];? > < / td >
      <td> <? php echo $data1['comment']; ? > < / td >
            < / tr >
      <? php} ? >
   < !-- SUBCONSULTA -- > 
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Se que necesito hacer esas consultas por medio de API's, lo pretendo hacer mas adelante, soy novato en esto**

Comment: Gracias por las recomendaciones.

Comment: No has explicado cuál es el problema.